# Failed to load JS and other support files while trying to checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript

I am trying to add a product in cart and check out the product, page still loading and it shown error message. enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Comment: try running upgrading, static content-deploy, cache commands

Comment: `rm -rf pub/static/*` and `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area frontend` should be enough to fix this. Also try clearing your browser cache and/or disabling it in developer tools under the network tab

Comment: Thanks for your response, It's work well for me.